# What do Ethhash and CliqueConfig refer to in the genesis config?

Tags: go-ethereum, genesis, ethash, configuration, clique

I don't see any real documentaiton on what these are or to what they refer.

Here is the structure in the `config` file:

```
// Various consensus engines
Ethash *EthashConfig `json:"ethash,omitempty"`
Clique *CliqueConfig `json:"clique,omitempty"`
```

Can I get a technical breakdown of what they are, how they work, and what they do?

Answer (score 2):

Ethash is the Proof-of-Work algorithm used by Ethereum. Design rationale and an explanation of the algorithm in pseudo-code can be found on the [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash) (and has been discussed in previous questions - see: [What proof of work function does Ethereum use?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/14/what-proof-of-work-function-does-ethereum-use)).

Clique is the protocol used in Ethereum's Proof-of-Authority testnet, named Rinkeby.

If you're really asking what those two variables equate to code-wise, then the logical conclusion, if you follow the code through in that file (i.e. [`config.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/6d6a5a93370371a33fb815d7ae47b60c7021c86a/params/config.go#L145)), is the creation of the `genesis.json` file, with the `engine` field being dependent on which type of chain you're creating it for.

```
// String implements the fmt.Stringer interface.
func (c *ChainConfig) String() string {
    var engine interface{}
    switch {
    case c.Ethash != nil:
        engine = c.Ethash
    case c.Clique != nil:
        engine = c.Clique
    default:
        engine = "unknown"
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("{ChainID: %v Homestead: %v DAO: %v DAOSupport: %v EIP150: %v EIP155: %v EIP158: %v Byzantium: %v Engine: %v}",
        c.ChainId,
        c.HomesteadBlock,
        c.DAOForkBlock,
        c.DAOForkSupport,
        c.EIP150Block,
        c.EIP155Block,
        c.EIP158Block,
        c.ByzantiumBlock,
        engine,
    )
}
```