# What algorithm Ethereum use POS(proof of shake) or POW(proof of work)?

Tags: proof-of-stake, consensus, proof-of-work

I am very much curious to know what algorithm Ethereum is using and what is the impact of this algorithm in the current blockchain .

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/14/what-proof-of-work-function-does-ethereum-use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ethereum currently uses a Proof of Work algorithm called Ethash, implementation details of which can be found on the [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash).

The plan is to move to a Proof of Stake algorithm called Casper at some point in the future. Current estimates from Vitalik put the chances of moving to PoS in 2017 at [between 50% and 80%](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5lfugz/eip_186_modified/dbvu8fd/?context=3).

Further details about Ethereum's proposed use of PoS can be found at the following places:

- How Casper works: [How does the Casper proof of stake algorithm work?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102/how-does-the-casper-proof-of-stake-algorithm-work)
- [PoS FAQ wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Proof-of-Stake-FAQ)
- Vitalik's PoS [Design Philosophy](https://medium.com/@VitalikButerin/a-proof-of-stake-design-philosophy-506585978d51#.6lwqzftt0)
- A 5-part write-up of the history of Casper (part 1 is [here](https://medium.com/@Vlad_Zamfir/the-history-of-casper-part-1-59233819c9a9#.ht90d0ct1))