# What diagrams exist to illustrate the Ethereum blockchain creation process?

Tags: blockchain, architecture

I have found the below diagram (and this [explanation](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/13347/34190)) useful in understanding how blockchains work in general:

[image: Bitcoin Block Data] [[Illustration by Matthäus Wander (Wikimedia)]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrKX0.png)

[This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/494/820) goes on to say that

> Ethereum's actual blockchain structure is somewhat more elaborate...

I'd like to understand how the turing complete smart contract programming language fits into Ethereum's blockchain creation and confirmation.

This diagram, [from here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/757/820), shows a similar diagram, adapted for Ethereum:

[image]

What other diagrams are there to illustrate the Ethereum blockchain process and overall architecture?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I couldn't find what I was after so I did my own:

[image]

Comment: So great! Do you have a high res / vector version ready? Cant read the small parts...

Comment: @RolandKofler Thanks, I'll see what I can do. Will be a while though. I can just about read the small text when I click on it and zoom in.

Comment: it is an amazing work. Try to read the account, transaction, block header text etc.

Comment: @RolandKofler Fair point - it's only just legible; I'll see if I can increase resolution.

Comment: yeah need to hang it on a wall :--)

Comment: @RolandKofler I've re-uploaded it as a high-res .png (exported as 120 dpi). I have a 300dpi version but above imgur's 2MB capacity. I also have an SVG version.

Comment: Thanks, would you fileshare the SVG version? With Dropbox, Gdrive,...? That would be so amazing having it printable!

Comment: Done: https://github.com/4c656554/BlockchainIllustrations/tree/master/Ethereum - Let me know if you see any errors (I'll update and give credit).

Comment: So great! I will examine next week when I have time, going to the thompson reuters Hackethon...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about all the diagrams existing , but you can find a nice explication and schema of the patricia merkle tree here vs bitcoin merkle tree :

https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/11/15/merkling-in-ethereum/