# What is the exact data structure of each block?

Tags: blockchain, blocks, yellow-paper

is there any document / diagram describing Ethereum block structure in similar way as https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block?

I know I can find implementation at https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/blocks.py but I am still missing some information as bytesize and similar...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the [Ethereum Yellow Paper (YP)](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper) and related [Ethereum block architecture](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/268/42).

Here are the main pieces of a block and the YP has all the sizes:

> 4.3. The Block. The block in Ethereum is the collection of relevant pieces of information (known as the block header), H, together with
>   information corresponding to the comprised transactions, T, and a set
>   of other block headers U that are known to have a parent equal to the
>   present block’s parent’s parent.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an illusatration adapted from [another answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2286/820) -> definitions summarised from [the yellow paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper):

[image]

See also Equation (35) of [the yellow paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper). On github [here](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper/blob/master/Paper.tex#L409), Latex format:

```
The component types are defined thus:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}[t]{lclclcl}
H_p \in \mathbb{B}_{32} & \wedge & H_o \in \mathbb{B}_{32} & \wedge & H_c \in \mathbb{B}_{20} & \wedge \\
H_r \in \mathbb{B}_{32} & \wedge & H_t \in \mathbb{B}_{32} & \wedge & H_e \in \mathbb{B}_{32} & \wedge \\
H_b \in \mathbb{B}_{256} & \wedge & H_d \in \mathbb{P} & \wedge & H_i \in \mathbb{P} & \wedge \\
H_l \in \mathbb{P} & \wedge & H_g \in \mathbb{P} & \wedge & H_s \in \mathbb{P}_{256} & \wedge \\
H_x \in \mathbb{B} & \wedge & H_m \in \mathbb{B}_{32} & \wedge & H_n \in \mathbb{B}_{8}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{B}_n = \{ B: B \in \mathbb{B} \wedge \lVert B \rVert = n \}
\end{equation}
```