# Who will run the network after proof of stake?

Tags: mining, proof-of-stake

Currently miners act as 'servers' for the Ethereum network, by doing all the needed work for Dapps to run, calculating, saving data etc..

Am I correct?

My question is this:
who will run all of this after move to Proof of Stake?

Comment: Consider making the answer as accepted, you can do it by checking the tick sign under votes.

Answer (score 3):

[Review of Casper, Ethereum’s proposed Proof of Stake Algorithm](http://bytemaster.github.io/2015/08/08/Review-of-Casper-Ethereums-proposed-Proof-of-Stake-Algorithm/)

> Anyone can participate in block production by posting a bond. After
>   posting a bond you have an opportunity to bet on which block will be
>   included next. The incentives are such that you make money by betting
>   with the eventual consensus and lose money by betting against the
>   consensus. Any crypto-graphically provable misbehavior results in the
>   forfeit of the bond.

#### This will enable all miners to continue; but in a competitive way.

Read [Why does Ethereum plan to move to Proof of Stake?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/75/259)