# Is switching to Proof of Stake (PoS) makes GPU mining worthless?

Tags: mining, proof-of-stake, gpu

Is switching to Proof of Stake (PoS) makes GPU mining no longer available?

Comment: You could also look at http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3531/405

Comment: Actually, I think that one is a better fit :)