# How would Proof of Stake affect rigs running GPUs (480,580)

Tags: ether, proof-of-stake

I noticed through a few articles about how proof of stake is a likely progression for the ETH project.  I agree with the principles and the security benefits it gives, but how would it in real terms affect the **physical process of mining with a GPU**?

Comment: Also: [Is switching to Proof of Stake (PoS) makes GPU mining worthless?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6102/is-switching-to-proof-of-stake-pos-makes-gpu-mining-worthless?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

There will be no **physical process of mining**. New coins will be minted by staking. You will be able to use the GPU for mining other GPU based coins.

Essentially - your GPU will be useless for ethereuem.