# If Ethereum switches to POS, does that mean I can never mine coin if I just have a few Ethereum?

Tags: proof-of-stake

If Ethereum switches to Proof-of-Stake, does that mean I can never mine it if I just have, let say, a few Ether? Does it mean the more Ethereum you have, the more chance you have to mine Ether?

Comment: Does that answer your question: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3523/87