# Will miners still make Ether after POS?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, cpp-ethereum, proof-of-stake, ethereumjs

So, I am new to the entire crypto currency idea although, I am a software developer and I have been planning for years to create a CRM that is fully autonomous and exceptionally secure. Ether's code will allow me to do just that through blockchain. 
This is something I have been working for the past 2 years and once I have a demo. I will be more than happy to share it with you when the demo is ready.

Although, I have been introduced to the idea of POS and although it does add a layer of security I was thinking.... that many miners might abandon the daily mining hence, the CRM app that I am planning might stop performing if there is no miners to handle the request.

As I said, I am new to the whole idea of BlockChain and I might have misunderstood the whole “POS” concept when it comes to the miners.

Try to give me some insight. Thank you in advance.

Comment: (I had to look it up: CRM = Customer Relationship Management system.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do miners profit post-PoS, if at all, how will new miners get their start, and who will execute the EVM byte code (and why)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3523/how-do-miners-profit-post-pos-if-at-all-how-will-new-miners-get-their-start-a)

Comment: it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Hi there. What is your specific question? "Will miners make Ether after POS?" is very similar to "How do miners profit post-POS...". Is that what you want to know?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks not close to that... anyway Etherkimist answered my question bellow.

Comment: Understood - if you're happy with their answer then that's all that matters :-)

Answer (score 1):

**POS** is a consensus protocol which aims to replace the **POW** waste of computing power and electricity (bitcoin consumes as much electricity as Denmark by 2020). In **POS**, the miners will still be here, but they are chosen in a deterministic way, depending on their stake.

Comment: With pos is better to call them "validators" instead of "miners".