# What is delegated proof of stake and why is it not suitable for Ethereum?

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper

Ethereum will switch to Proof Of Stake in some future hard fork called Serenity. For this putpose a new Proof Of Stake protocol called Casper is being developed.[[1]](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9/why-does-ethereum-plan-to-move-to-proof-of-stake/75#75)

However, there are quite a few cryptocurrencies out there that already use proof of stake, most of them a version called Delegated Proof Of Stake, some of them even adding a version to show how progressive they are (DPOS 2.0, DPOS 3.0).

What are key features of this Delegated Proof Of Stake as compared to current state of Casper and why is it not sufficient for Ethereum *according to the Ethereum Foundation guys*? Is it even secure enough in existing implementations?

Comment: "why is it not sufficient for Ethereum" this is an implied assumption - please refer to the source of such claim - maybe it *is* sufficient

Comment: The claim is not mine, it stems from the fact that the Ethereum Foundation develops its own protocol, so existing DPOS is not deemed sufficient

Comment: Clarified the question

Answer (score 1):

Here is a comparison on Reddit, favoring Casper PoS
https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6s6eh8/delegated_proofofstake_vs_proofofstake_also_im/

Here is a review of Casper from the creator of DPoS.
http://bytemaster.github.io/2015/08/08/Review-of-Casper-Ethereums-proposed-Proof-of-Stake-Algorithm/

Comment: Note that the second of those links is 2.5 years old.